# which is better Java program or stored procedure for infinitely running queries

Tags: java, mysql, performance, stored-procedures, infinite

In a MySQL environment, with a dedicated MySQL server and a dedicated app server, which is better -

a. Running an infinite java code on an app server that connects to a database server, fetches some records based on join and then inserts them into the database

-OR-

b. Running an infinite stored procedure on the database that performs the insert based on join (select)

Need answer in terms of execution time, db load, memory requirement and ability of the db to continue processing other inserts/updates

Comment: UPDATE: I solved my problem by writing insert/update triggers for the tables I was using in my join operation. This way, I got rid of the continuous polling. I can now insert data (after select..join) into the other table as soon as it arrives in the table I am interested in reading from. 

I haven't performed exhaustive memory tests but with tests using thousands of inserts/updates in the table (which has the trigger written on), the CPU load is minimal (<5%) and not much change in average memory consumption.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about execution time, db load and memory requirement but in my experience it is better to do all the logic work in your business layer (instead of db). Besides, stored procedures are less scalabale and harder to maintain in big projects. So my choice is A.

Comment: Please explain why stored procedures are less scalable?

Comment: ... And also why are the harder to maintain?

Answer (score 2):

Some info is missing, but I'm guessing as for that:

The rows are most obviously not coming in an an infinite rate.

You are most probably polling as for that. That is, you are making some sort of `sleep()` between cycles.

If you're not - then you should know you could be pressing a high load on the database server in either case.

So, assuming there'll be *some sort* of sleep (let's say **1** second, for simplicity), it turns out there's not much difference between you Java code and the stored routine code. Why is that?

- The sleeps are idle any way. No locks will be held during sleep time.
- Any query you issue in Java code must be issued from routine code and vice versa.
- There is not much (or at all) computational complexity to your code. You're most probably checking on some `MAX(id)` from the target table, then `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id > max_id_as_just_calculated`, or something similar.

Execution time may actually be somewhat in favor of routine code, since you do not need to ship result sets back and forth between MySQL and Java. Moreover, you can just `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` in one query, instead of translating result set into java objects/primitives, then preparing new `INSERT` query, translating back to MySQL data.

In terms of DB load I see no real difference, again with a slight improvement on routine side due to network delivery time (time in which locks may still be held).

**Considerations:**

How would you invoke this procedure from Java? It would run for an indefinite amount of time. So would you dedicate a thread to it?

Suppose it crashed (error of some sorts) -- need to be able to re-execute it (not a big deal, just an issue to consider).

You could execute it via the [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) -- that would solve many of the above issues: instead of looping via the routine, let the scheduler invoke it every *X* seconds. But then - consider locks again.

My own preference: I would probably use Java code, or I would use the event scheduler if I'm comfortable adding this logic to the RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is such a thing as an "infinitely running query".  Perhaps you mean a query that is run **repeatedly**.

Anyway, as a general rule, you will get better throughput if you can avoid the overheads of transferring large amounts data backwards and forwards between the database and an application.  On the other hand, if the "thing" you are trying to do is computationally intensive (rather than data intensive) then doing the computation in the application (running on a different machine to the DB) is going to reduce DB load.

> Need answer in terms of execution time, db load, memory requirement and ability of the db to continue processing other inserts/updates

It is not possible to quantify these things in the general case, but there are obvious trade-offs:

- Avoiding transferring lots of data reduces network load and CPU load (in database drivers).
- But doing "everything" on the database increases the load on the database.

How it will work out in practice will depend critically on the details of the actual use-case.

Answer (score 1):

For some databases I would opt for the stored procedure. Why shift data about and besides the database has knowledge about that data.

But - and it is a bit failing (IMHO) that MySql you cannot have `commit` or `rollback` inside a stored procedure. So I would think that an infinite stored procedure in the MySql context will not work as expected.

Comment: Interesting.. Never thought about this. Though I solved my problem using triggers, this is a good thing to know and remember.

Comment: Interesting to know - Sybase you can have commit and rollbacks.

Comment: I also believe in the database should look after itself - i.e. maintain integrity.